# What's enderpearl's speed in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm working on a calculator for enderpearl trajectory calculation and I need to know at what speed enderpearls are travelling through air.

Comment: You want to make a calculator mainly based on one number and you don't have that number? :D Anyway, can't you find it out with experiments? Sure, an exact number would require looking into the code, but if it's something point nine nine, you can assume it's the rounded number.

Answer (score 3):

Enderpearls can have any amount of speed, they follow the same rules as any other object such as snowballs. Throw it up, and it will slow down. Speed it up with pistons and TNT and it will travel much faster.

For reference, steve will throw enderpearls at around 23m/s when taken an average of a normal throw (to be precise when thrown at a 15 degree angle the average travel speed of steve is 23m/s).

However, the fastest pearl cannon ever build achieved 3,000 m/s with an enderpearl.

[Reference](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Transportation)